# How to set mui-x datepicker calendar outlined?

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, calendar, variant

I'm using "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker", I want to get an outlined calendar like this image.
[outlined calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ONg6.png)

I have tried `` "& .MuiPickersDay-root": {borderRadius: "2px", background: "#ffffff", border: `1px solid #c6cbce`,}, `` but I got this [wrong calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbEbA.png). It's not what I want.

How can I get the first link Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution of how you can make your calendar popup have borders like the outlined you are trying.

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sound-lfkcrv?file=/demo.tsx)

You need to add the styling using the `PopperProps` of the `DatePicker`

```
    // Set your styling
    const calendarSx = {
        "& .MuiPickersDay-dayWithMargin": {
          borderRadius: "0",
          outline: "1px solid black",
          margin: "0px 1px 0 0"
        },
        "& .MuiDayPicker-weekContainer": { margin: "1px" }
      };


 {/* Addit to your DatePicker component     */}
    <DesktopDatePicker
      label="Date desktop"
      inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      PopperProps={{
        sx: calendarSx
      }}
    />
```